# Incorrect message "Caps Lock is on" when entering password

Tags: bug, mobile, login

I am authenticating on the site *[Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)*. I am entering my password.

1. When I press Shift, the site says "Caps Lock is on". This is incorrect.
2. When Shift is released, the site still says "Caps Lock is on". This is even more incorrect.

I have Safari on iOS 7 on an iPad mini.

Comment: With Safari on iOS 8.2, the bug occurs too.